# How to make my character only move to my mouse x position and stay in the Y?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

# pygame initialize
pygame.init()

# screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 900))

# title icon
icon = pygame.image.load("image/stick_man_icon.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("stick man bizarre adventure")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player stick man
playerimg = pygame.image.load("image/stickman.png")
playerY = 700


# player
def player(playerX):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (playerX, playerY))


# pygame loop
running = True
while running:
    # mouse position 
    mx = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     
    # rgb screen colors
    screen.fill((34, 139, 34))
    
    # event for
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    # game character movement
    player(mx)
    
    # screen display
    pygame.display.update()
```

How do I make it so that the character stay the same Y but when I move my change my cursor X it will move with the cursor?
-e-e-e--e-e-e-e-e--e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e

Comment: What's with the garbage text? What is this - some kind of troll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe return value of [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) is a tuple. Just because you don't need the y-coordinate, you can't just skip it:

<s>`mx = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`</s>

```py
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

or

```py
mx, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```